# Reading weights from HDF5 with C#

Tags: c#, hdf5

i have hdf5 file (.h5), i can use python to open the file and extract the weight and biases that are stored in it using (get_weights function), but i want to exract those weights using c# program, and i can't find a clear documentation for hdf5.NET, so if anybody who's done this before can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not required to use specific technologies to implement what you have in mind, you may consider HDFql (http://www.hdfql.com) which is a high-level language to manage HDF files easily (think SQL). Using HDFql in C#, opening an HDF5 file (e.g. `example.h5`) can be done like this:

```
HDFql.Execute("USE FILE example.h5");
```

After opening the file and assuming that your weight is stored in a dataset named `Weight` of datatype `float`, you could read it as follows:

```
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM Weight");
```

From there, you can retrieve the value of `Weight` with the cursor provided by HDFql:

```
HDFql.CursorNext();
System.Console.WriteLine("Value of weight: {0}", HDFql.CursorGetFloat());
```